# Test existence of object properties in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Using jQuery with IE doesn't work for me.

I have ajax response:

```
{"update":{"WaterLever":null},"missing":["WaterBallast"]}
```

Firing different functions upon response:

```
$.post(...
...
function(data) {
  markMissing(data['missing']);
  fldUpdate(data['update']);
}
```

all is working in chrome/FF but only fldUpdate in IE.

IE doesn't find the elements in the object, tried .indexOf, (val in data) etc...

```
function markMissing(data) {
  //loop all fields in form..
  $('[id^=cont]').each(function() {
    var s = this.id;
    //discard prefix 'cont_' in id. 
    var fld = s.substring(5);
    if(fld in data) { //this doesn't work
    //if(data.indexOf(fld)) { //this neither.
      $(this).addClass('missing');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('missing');
    }
  });
}
```

Thanks for any input

Comment: Are you sure `fld` is what you want it to be in IE? It's probably not what you think it is.

Comment: What version of IE? IE<9 does not support indexOf, and -in my experience- can behave oddly when it comes to assync callbacks (like calling readystatechange handler once, when readystatechange is 1, but not for 2,3 and -crucially- 4)... try debugging with dev-tools (F12) and setting breakpoints, check the `substring` return value, too... as I recall it's as unpredictable as a drunk boxer (dangerous, often painful)

Comment: Try `if (data[fld])` or `if (data.hasOwnProperty(fld))` if `data[fld]` is allowed to be `0`, `false`, etc. If it doesn't work, then something's wrong with `fld`.

Comment: nothing is what i want it to be in IE, but fld is fine. Currently suspecting some bad assignment of (this).

Comment: please note, code works fine by replacing with if (true) {, being all fields are marked as missed.

Comment: Are you by any chance using the same ID for multiple DOM elements?

Comment: I've created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLn9d/) for you showing that the code is correct (works under IE for me).

Comment: @freakish, thanks for your help. Please post an answer and I'll upvote you.